# JMeter - Can I combine 2 user variables into one?

Tags: java, apache, jmeter, user-variables

I was wondering if you are able to combine two user variables into one. For example I have one user variable which is defined as the location of a root folder, and a second variable defined as a location from the root, down into a subfolder, and what I'm asking if its possible to put variable 1+variable 2 = a full path way?

so for example I have one variable as:

```
testData.directory = ${__P(testData.directory,C:\Users\MURPHYA1\Desktop\JMeter bodies)}
testData.testCases = ${__P(testData.testCases,\JMeter Basket body files)
```

and what i want to produce is: C:\Users\MURPHYA1\Desktop\JMeter bodies\JMeter Basket body files

Is this possible?

UPDATE

I now have the following config and quite a few test variables just for testing:
[JMeter Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmIEM.png)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Add a second "User Defined Variables" element after yours. 
There every variable will be replaced by the values defined in your first element.

```
- User Defined Variables
- - test1 = a/
- - test2 = b
- User Defined Variables 2
- - test3 = ${test1}${test2}
```

Comment: no need for 2 user defined variables config elements, one is enough

Comment: Sadly that doesn't seem to work in JMeter under under defined variables. I found the same resolution as @Dan Seibert which is you have to call one variable after another, such as ${test1}${test2}/file.txt

Comment: Ideally, we wanted to user variables to which would be combined into one, but there doesnt seem to be any way to do that.

Comment: @PMDUBIK-INGENIERIE I am using JMeter 2.9 and the described way is the only possible for me. In one config element the vars are not replaced no matter which order i use.

Comment: Ah Christopher, you and gentleman and a scholar. I didnt read the part about adding a second user defined variables. I thought you meant just add another variable. Thank you so much

Answer (score 3):

try this

${__V(${keyword1}${keyword2})}

Comment: Please explain your approach. This would help all a bit more.

Comment: @Raghu Ram,k Using this approach, the key also gets appended in between values of both variables i.e. value-of-keyword1-keyword1-value-of-keyword2

Answer (score 1):

I was NOT able to combine 2 variables into one in jmeter.  I tried several approaches, but ended up using the two variables side by side in the rest of the test plan. :-(

Comment: Yea I found the same thing this morning. Its not the worst resolution but still annoying

Comment: It is possible. Please see my answer. I am working with JMeter 2.9.

Answer (score 1):

Best way to combine to variables in Jmeter is by using __V() function which can be used to evaluate composite variables.

Example:
There are 2 JMeter Variables:

myVar_1 with the value of foo

myVar_2 with the value of bar

The syntax is:

```
${__V(PREFIX${POSTFIX})} // in this case myVar_ is PREFIX, 1&2 POSTFIX
```

Lets 'assume you want to use a different variable for each Thread. In this case the you will call __V() function like this

```
${__V(myVar_${__threadNum})}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a User Defined Variable with name **test** and value:

- ${testData.directory}${testData.testCases}

And then use : ${__evalVar(test)} in place

Also it is better to use / instead of \ for path properties and variables as they will work both in Linux and Windows.

Comment: I have tried that, with the following line:

testDate.full ${__P(testData.full,${testData.directory}${testData.testCases})}

but that still doesnt work. I assume I am just missing something

Comment: Don't use P, just add a User Defined Variable and create a new variable of your choice with value I have goven

Comment: I now have tried the following:

test1 C:\Users\MURPHYA1\Desktop\JMeter bodies 
test2 \JMeter Basket body files
test3 ${test1}${test2} 

and still nothing. Am I just missing something?

Comment: I have updated with an picture. Not too sure if you can see it

Answer (score 0):

For example you have 2 variables:

1. A variable from Regular Extractor:    `${employeeID}`
2. Second variable is a simple Variable defined in User Defined Variables: `Test1 =   ${__Random(14,25,)}`
3. Now we concatinate/combine this 2 variables, it will look like this:

   ${__V(employeeID_${Test1})}
   ${employeeID} + $ {Test1} =  ${__V(employeeID_${Test1})}

[__V function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__V)

Answer (score 0):

BeanShell Prozessor:

```
String var1 = vars.get("var1");
String var2 = vars.get("var2");
vars.put("var3", var1+"."+var2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use in BeanShell PostProcessor:

```
vars.put ("folder", vars.get("testData.directory") + vars.get("testData.testCases"))
```

So once you have:
var testData.directory = ${__P(testData.directory,"C:\Users\MURPHYA1\Desktop\JMeter bodies")}
var testData.testCases = ${__P(testData.testCases,"\JMeter Basket body files")

You will end up with concatenating the two variables into

```
folder = "C:\Users\MURPHYA1\Desktop\JMeter bodies\JMeter Basket body files"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using JMeter 5.6.2 the following solution worked for me:

My misson was to get a file path like this:

```
C:\tmp\jmeter\results_<date>\<time>_view-results-tree.xml
```

e.g.:

```
C:\tmp\jmeter\results_2024-01-04\19-29-00_view-results-tree.xml
```

So I created 2 ConfigElements "User Defined Variables".

The first one had to contain all variables which should be combined in the second one:

[image]

In the second "User Defined Variables" I used the following syntax to combine my variables:

```
${__V(${variable1}${variable2}${variable3})}
```

see:
[image]

The variable "resultFilePrefix" could then be used as prefix for my final result file name, see:
[image]